# Setting DOM properites in one-liner

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to rewrite the below as a single expression? I like to code in vanilla js and want to make my code less verbose

```
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.property1 = 1,
div.property2 = 2,
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but at the cost of creating another object and looping through its properties via [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {property1: 1, property2: 2}));
```

With line breaks:

```
document.body.appendChild(
    Object.assign(
        document.createElement("div"),
        {property1: 1, property2: 2}
    )
);
```

Gratuitous live example: ;-)

```js
document.body.appendChild(
    Object.assign(
        document.createElement("div"),
        {
            className: "example",
            id: "ex",
            textContent: "Hi there"
        }
    )
);
```

```css
.example {
    color: green;
}
#ex {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For insterest. Based on T.J's answer, if using helper functions you could have the much less verbose:
`body.ac(as(ce("div"), { property1: 1, property2: 2 }));`